# Find $BF$ in the following question.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral with right angled at $A$ and $C$. Points $E$ and $F$ are on the diagonal $AC$ such that $DE$ and $BF$ are both perpendicular to $AC$. They are asking $BF$. If $AE=3$, $DE=5$, $CE=7$.

This is a sum based on the principles of similarity and basic proportionality theorem and basic geometry. I tried but I couldn't get it.
I tried similarity between ∆DEF and ∆BFC but I couldn't find FC so I was unable to solve it

Comment: Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/782505).

Comment: What have you tried show in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is the figure of the given situation. Let $EF=x$.

In $\triangle DAE$, $$\tan \theta=\frac{DE}{AE}=\frac{5}{3}$$
In $\triangle BFA$, $\angle FAB=(90°-\theta)$ $$\therefore \tan(90°-\theta)=\frac{BF}{AF}=\frac{BF}{3+x}\dots\tag{1}$$

Now, in $\triangle DCE$, $$\tan\alpha=\frac{5}{7}$$ In $\triangle CFB$, $\angle FCB=(90°-\alpha)$ $$\therefore \tan(90°-\alpha) =\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{BF}{7-x}\dots\tag{2}$$

Divide equation $1$ and $2$, which gives us $x=4$. Now, you can find $BF$.

Comment: I have a doubt . How did you manage to get AF=7?

Comment: @A studious student, I'm editing it. Soon you'll get to know. By the time, you can show your attempt in the question as I can't provide direct solution without any prior knowledge of user regarding the context.

Comment: I came across this question in an examination. I don't have the paper right now. But I'll tell you the method I took

Comment: Edit that in the question. :-)

Comment: I used similarity between∆DEF and ∆BFC.. But as I couldn't find AF I was not able to solve it

Comment: @A studious student, I think you got the answer now!

Comment: They are not similar triangles so your method doesn't work. Through some angle chasing, you can find a pair of triangles that are similar.

Comment: @doubt nut. Thank you for providing some hints for solving the sum

Comment: @toby mak. Yes I Mistakenly took those two triangles

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There is no need for trigonometry at all. Using Doubtnut's diagram, $\angle FAB = 90º - \theta$, and since $\angle AFB$ is right as well, $\angle ABF = \theta$. Therefore $\Delta ADE \sim \Delta BAF$.

Using the same reasoning, $\Delta DCE \sim \Delta FBC$.

Now use the similarity of the triangles to construct two equations. At first, there might be too many unknown sides, but you can, in fact, express all the remaining sides in terms of $AF$. Solve for $AF$ and use this to find $BF$.

Can you continue?

---

The full solution is hidden behind the spoiler:

> $$\Delta ADE \sim \Delta BAF \Rightarrow \frac{3}{5} = \frac{BF}{AF} \tag{1}$$
>  $$\Delta DCE \sim \Delta FBC \Rightarrow \frac{5}{7} = \frac{CF}{BF} \tag{2}$$
>
>  From $(1)$, $BF = \frac{3}{5} AF$. Since $AC = AE + CE = 10$, $CF = 10 - AF$. Combining these two facts together:
>  $$\frac{5}{7} = \frac{10-AF}{(3/5) AF} \Rightarrow 3AF = 70 - 7AF \Rightarrow AF = 7$$
>
>  and since $BF = \frac{3}{5} AF$, $BF = \frac{21}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you for your hints also

Comment: @Toby Mark it should be BF=21/5.

Comment: Yep, thanks for spotting the typo.